# package.json in angular not updated when install package

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, package.json

When I try to installing a new package with `npm install [package name] --save` why my package.json file is not updated?

this is what I used at my project:
6.4.1 (npm version) and 6.1.4 (angular cli version).
[image]
thanks

Comment: Run `npm outdated` to check outdated packages. To install the newest of a package use, `npm install --save [package-name]@latest`

Comment: share the package.json.

Comment: in some version-control systems like TFS for example, your repository files are marked as `read-only` by default. make sure the package.json isn't write protected

Comment: how can I change that? @Stavm

Comment: I was uploaded my package.json file @manishkumar

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install --save [package-name]@latest
```

might do the trick